# If$f(z)$ is analytic , then what about $f'(z)?? $

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

If$f(z)$ is analytic ,  then what about $f'(z)$?

can we conclude that $f^{(k)}(z)$ is analytic for any k$\in $$ \mathbb{N} $

Comment: Yes. Use Taylor series locally, for instance.

Comment: There are several definitions of analytic. Which do you know?

Comment: Answer is yes. Since f is analytic it has a power series, then differentiate power series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah with cauchy's formula
$$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi} \int_{\partial B} \frac{f(\xi)}{(\xi - z_0)^{n+1}} \, \mathrm{d}\xi$$
you can calculate all derivates only knowing your function.

Maybe this will look easier, as $f$ is analytic it can be written as a power series 
$$f(z)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k $$
Using that you can change differention and summing you get that $f'$ is analytic too.

Comment: That it has derivatives of any order does not mean it's analytic.

Comment: @arbautjc analytic means complex differentiable (for me) as $f'$ is diffentiable it must be analytic too

Comment: Yes, sorry, complex derivative is all right. I had the real case in mind.

Comment: @arbautjc in real case the integral makes no sense or ?

Comment: I know :S It was some old reflex from real analysis courses, where we used *also* power series, but had to be very cautious with pathological cases like $\exp -{1 \over x}$. Sometimes reflexes are bad.

Comment: That's the difference between "$C^\infty$-smooth" vs "real analytic" (and real analytic functions can always be complexified).